# Random and sudden crash with assert "condition 'klass->inited' not met"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing a Xamarin application and all of a sudden the app crashes with SIGABRT at random points in the code. This only happens when running the app on iOS.

I upgraded Xamarin recently but I am not sure if it is related.

[Here is the full crash](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f97d9c2aad64d8fbd02bffdba7e2d7e) report, any help would be appreciated:

> 2016-03-31 08:44:46.078 I4UITouch[1815:341927] error: * Assertion at ../../../../../mono/mono/mini/aot-runtime.c:3993,
>   condition `klass->inited' not met 2016-03-31 08:44:46.080
>   I4UITouch[1815:341927] critical: Stacktrace:
>
> .
>   .
>   .
>
> I4UITouch[1815:341927] critical: 
>   ================================================================= Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
>
> ## application.

Comment: When posting crash reports I wold suggest using something like Gist as the formatting has gone awry here making it difficult to read :)

Comment: possible solution here:  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40672